# Adding claims with JWT for LinkedIn Social Login

Tags: c#, jwt, linkedin-api

I am using the [Nivatech.Framework.OAuthProviders Nuget package](http://building.papiri.rs/2018/05/how-to-add-linkedin-login-to-your-asp-net-core-app/) to Signin via linkedin.

However, I need to add claims using JWT. I need to specify if a user is an Admin, SuperUser or NormalUser.

I simply have no clue on how to do this ?

Note: Usually, for a username, password type of an authentication, I could add a userType as a Claim from my code. But, since its LinkedIn and handled separately by a 3rd party application I don't know how to do this, Can someone shed some light.